# jax-ws java client, generated from wsdl, gets response from webservice but the holders contain null value

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

I have generated client from a given wsdl file using jax-ws in a java enterprise application. the endpoint method receives 2 request parameters and several holders with mode.OUT. After calling endpoint action and receiving result, I see in my console logs that the request has been correctly sent and there is response received. However, the holders still contain null values. I have been searching the reasons for days now with no lock and I'm really frustrated. The resources on google suggest that this happens due to a problem or error in wsdl and there might be a mismatch between my code and the wsdl, Although I have created code from wsdl, So, it doesn't seem logical that there would be a conflict between the code and the wsdl. Any way, I have checked every thing, from ordering of params, namespaces, etc. , and found nothing. I would greatly appreciate any help. Especially that my company only waits for this to deploy next war file. Also, sopaUi returns results as expected. I have put my wsdl here. and my endpoint, too.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices">
    <wsdl:types xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices" xmlns:tns="http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices">
            <xs:element name="IbanInquiry">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="loginRequest" type="tns:LoginRequest" />
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:IbanInquiryRequest" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="IbanInquiryRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="IBAN" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="IbanInquiryResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestedIBAN" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountNumber" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountStatus" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountDescription" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountComment" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountOwners" nillable="false" type="tns:ArrayOfAccountOwner"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentCode" nillable="false" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentCodeValid" nillable="false" type="xs:decimal"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AlertCode" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ErrorDescription" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfAccountOwner">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AccountOwner" nillable="false" type="tns:accountOwner"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="accountOwner">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="LoginRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Username" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="B2BServiceException">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" nillable="false" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="TraceCode" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Translate" nillable="false" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="IbanInquiryDataIn" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IbanInquiry" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="IbanInquiryDataOut" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:IbanInquiryResponse" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="IB2BESB">
        <wsdl:operation name="IbanInquiry">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:IbanInquiryDataIn"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:IbanInquiryDataOut"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="HttpBindingIB2BESB_Services" type="tns:IB2BESB" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="IbanInquiry">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices/IbanInquiry" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="esbservice" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:HttpBindingIB2BESB_Services" name="HttpBindingIB2BE

SB_Services" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
                <soap:address location="http://epg.iic.local:4625/soap" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"/>
            </wsdl:port>
        </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

```
package com.payeshgaran.insurance.common.service.draft.ws.draftconfirmwebservice2;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;
import javax.xml.ws.Holder;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;


/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01
 * Generated source version: 2.2
 */
@WebService(name = "IB2BESB", targetNamespace = "http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices")
@XmlSeeAlso({
        ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface IB2BESB {



    @WebMethod(operationName = "IbanInquiry", action = "http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices/IbanInquiry")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "IbanInquiry", targetNamespace = "http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices", className = "com.payeshgaran.insurance.common.service.draft.ws.draftconfirmwebservice2.IbanInquiry")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "IbanInquiryResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.hosaco.ir/IB2BServices", className = "com.payeshgaran.insurance.common.service.draft.ws.draftconfirmwebservice2.IbanInquiryResponse")
    public void ibanInquiry(
            @WebParam(name = "loginRequest", targetNamespace = "")
            LoginRequest loginRequest,
            @WebParam(name = "request", targetNamespace = "")
            IbanInquiryRequest request,
            @WebParam(name = "RequestedIBAN", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> requestedIBAN,
            @WebParam(name = "AccountNumber", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> accountNumber,
            @WebParam(name = "AccountStatus", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> accountStatus,
            @WebParam(name = "AccountDescription", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> accountDescription,
            @WebParam(name = "AccountComment", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> accountComment,
            @WebParam(name = "AccountOwners", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<ArrayOfAccountOwner> accountOwners,
            @WebParam(name = "PaymentCode", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<BigDecimal> paymentCode,
            @WebParam(name = "PaymentCodeValid", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<BigDecimal> paymentCodeValid,
            @WebParam(name = "AlertCode", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> alertCode,
            @WebParam(name = "ErrorDescription", targetNamespace = "", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT)
            Holder<String> errorDescription);



}
```